# Yii - registerScriptFile not registering

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am trying to register jquery ui as a script as a certain view is rendered, so I can use the jquery ui dialog. The problem is that the files aren't being registered. Any ideas? Here's a code snippet. I can verify that the files are on the server.

```
# site/docs
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(BASE_URL . 'js/css/jquery-ui.css');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(BASE_URL . 'js/jquery-ui.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

I'm sure I am overlooking something small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your call to the script is wrong.

```
BASE_URL . '/js/css/jquery-ui.css')
```

etc. you need the forward slash.

Comment: also, you know that jquery ui is a registered core script, right? You can call it by Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery.ui');

Comment: Your answer worked. Thanks I feel dumb. the registerCoreScript also registered the UI, but the CSS seems to be missing unless I register the actual CSS file on my own.